# SQL Query - Large Number of Joins -

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization, inner-join

I have a SQL query that I'm using to pull in data from different tables for part details and fitment data. Unfortunately, the way the tables are laid out requires a lot of JOINs it seems. I currently have the following query and running it via phpmyadmin just displays a Loading screen, so I imagine it's timing out and wouldn't work in production.

I've added indexes on the tables and columns joined. I've optimized the database via phpmyadmin, but I'm still stumped as to how this should or could be done. Do I have to split up the queries and combine them with UNION? If so, I'm not even sure how that'd work with this or IF it'd work.

Please help. :-)

```
EXPLAIN SELECT Import_Values.base_vehicle_id,
    Import_Values.qty,
    Import_Values.part_type_id,
    Import_Values.part_id,
    Import_Values.position_id,
    Import_Values.note,
    Parts.partterminologyname,
    BaseVehicle.YearID,
    Make.MakeName,
    Model.modelname,
    SubModel.SubModelName,
    EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationName,
    EngineVIN.EngineVINName,
    EngineBase.Liter,
    EngineBase.CC,
    EngineBase.CID,
    EngineBase.Cylinders,
    EngineBase.BlockType,
    EngineBase.EngBoreIn,
    EngineBase.EngBoreMetric,
    EngineBase.EngStrokeIn,
    EngineBase.EngStrokeMetric,
    FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeName,
    FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeName,
    FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeName,
    FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignName,
    Aspiration.AspirationName,
    CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeName,
    FuelType.FuelTypeName,
    IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeName,
    Mfr.MfrName,
    EngineVersion.EngineVersion,
    Valves.ValvesPerEngine,
    BedLength.BedLength,
    BedLength.BedLengthMetric,
    BedType.BedTypeName
    FROM 
    Import_Values
    INNER JOIN BaseVehicle 
        ON Import_Values.base_vehicle_id=BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID
    INNER JOIN Parts 
        ON Import_Values.part_type_id=Parts.PartTerminologyID
    INNER JOIN Make
        ON BaseVehicle.MakeID=Make.MakeID
    INNER JOIN Model
        ON BaseVehicle.ModelID=Model.ModelID
    INNER JOIN Vehicle
        ON Import_Values.base_vehicle_id=Vehicle.BaseVehicleID
    INNER JOIN SubModel
        ON Vehicle.SubModelID=SubModel.SubModelID
    INNER JOIN VehicleToEngineConfig
        ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToEngineConfig.VehicleID
    INNER JOIN EngineConfig
        ON VehicleToEngineConfig.EngineConfigID=EngineConfig.EngineConfigID
    INNER JOIN EngineDesignation
        ON EngineConfig.EngineDesignationID=EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationID
    INNER JOIN EngineVIN
        ON EngineConfig.EngineVINID=EngineVIN.EngineVINID
    INNER JOIN EngineBase
        ON EngineConfig.EngineBaseID=EngineBase.EngineBaseID
    INNER JOIN FuelDeliveryConfig
        ON EngineConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID=FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID
    INNER JOIN FuelDeliveryType
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryTypeID=FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelDeliverySubType
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliverySubTypeID=FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelSystemControlType
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemControlTypeID=FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelSystemDesign
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemDesignID=FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignID
    INNER JOIN Aspiration
        ON EngineConfig.AspirationID=Aspiration.AspirationID
    INNER JOIN CylinderHeadType
        ON EngineConfig.CylinderHeadTypeID=CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelType
        ON EngineConfig.FuelTypeID=FuelType.FuelTypeID
    INNER JOIN IgnitionSystemType
        ON EngineConfig.IgnitionSystemTypeID=IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeID
    INNER JOIN Mfr
        ON EngineConfig.EngineMfrID=Mfr.MfrID
    INNER JOIN EngineVersion
        ON EngineConfig.EngineVersionID=EngineVersion.EngineVersionID
    INNER JOIN Valves
        ON EngineConfig.ValvesID=Valves.Valvesid
    INNER JOIN VehicleToBedConfig
        ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToBedConfig.VehicleID
    INNER JOIN BedConfig
        ON VehicleToBedConfig.BedConfigID=BedConfig.BedConfigID
    INNER JOIN BedLength
        ON BedConfig.BedLengthID=BedLength.BedLengthID
    INNER JOIN BedType
        ON BedConfig.BedTypeID=BedType.BedTypeID
```

Comment: what a bad database design! Do you really need all that data in 1 query?

Comment: Hey Sergio. It really is terrible. Unfortunately, it's the standard design for data provided by a third party that handles the fitment data for auto parts.

Comment: Well, each table can store thousands of records, so do you need all those records in 1 query or you can just pull some filters, so final query will have at least `where` clause?

Comment: Hey Sergio. I wish the data could be filtered down. Unfortunately, all of the records do have to be pulled. I'm sorry for being so difficult!

Comment: Can you explain **why** all these combinations of records need to be pulled?

Comment: Can you post the results of the explain you have done. If properly indexed that query is fine (I have done more joins in a single query).

Answer (score 4):

The database design is fine.  This is an example of normalization.  From what I can tell, the tables and columns are well-named.  I assume the id on each table is a primary key, which would have an index.  The query should be pretty fast, unless there is a large amount of data (relative to available memory).

Some of your tables are suggesting many-to-many relationships.  One possibility is that the query is creating a Cartesian product of rows from different dimensions (within a vehicle) that is multiplying the rows.  For instance, there might be multiple `parts` per vehicle and multiple `EngineConfig` (this is purely a guess as an example), so 100 parts and 20 configs would result in 2,000 rows.

To debug this, start at the top and work down:

```
select *
FROM Import_Values INNER JOIN
     BaseVehicle 
     ON Import_Values.base_vehicle_id=BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID
```

Look at the results and be sure that you are getting the *rows* you expect -- and not any more.  Then continue adding one join at a time until you spot the issue (either performance or too many rows).

Comment: `EXPLAIN` can show you which JOIN's are contributing to the large amount of rows. Look for rows with type different than 'eq_ref' and their row count in the explain result.